# Why perstashop cannot connect to db in release mode?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.7

I have an e-commerce site which is built by Prestashop 1.7. when my site is running under debug mode everything is ok and site and back-office work properly. but when I turn off my site debug mode my back-office start to crash and when I am navigating from dashboard main page to somewhere else like products list or setting section only an empty white page is showing. I look in my page Inspect and found that there is an Internal Server Error (500) for loading page.
then I look at my site hosting log and found that there is a database connection
error:

> Access denied for user 'mysite'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/mysite/domains/mysite.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43

I look at my database connection parameters inside **app/config/parameters.php** but my database user name is not **mysite** but is **mysite_dbuser**. I am wondering about this changing username when site mode is modified to release mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. there is two cache (prod/dev) inside **var/cache** directory which must de deleted after changing site debug mode.